# Problems using Class Methods as Callbacks

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I have a weird issue that I am facing while using class methods as callbacks. I am going to try and summarize the issue here.

```
class A{
protected:
   int alpha;
} 
class B:public A{ 
 public:
   B(){ alpha = 1; }
   void some_func(){ alpha = 2; }
   void odom_callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg){ std::cout<<alpha;}
}
int main(){
B * var = new B;
B->some_ func();
ros::spin();
}
```

Now, when the odom callback is called, I would expect it to print 2 for the value of alpha. However, in the callback it keeps printing 1. I know for sure that `some_func()` has been called. However I do not know why in the callback it uses the first initialized value. Of course my real code is more complex, though I tried to illustrate the fault in this example. Please let me know what you think might be going wrong.
Thanks!
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49935/problems-using-class-methods-as-callbacks./) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-12-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-12-07**:
Try making your example more realistic, i.e. a real node that can compile, with a real subscriber, etc. and test it. It should work as expected. Meaning that your real and more complex code has a different issue. But try this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you meant:

```
B * var = new B;
var->some_ func();
```

ant not

```
B * var = new B;
B->some_ func();
```

As brice suggested, post the real example which is failing, or a link to it and a description of the relevant lines.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2